Are there any alternatives to NVIDIA’s AI Chat with RTX?
I downloaded and attempted to install the NVIDIA AI chatbot from this link:
https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/ai-on-rtx/chat-with-rtx-generative-ai/
However, it requires an RTX 30-40 series graphics card.
I am interested in an individual AI chatbot to which I can feed my personal files and collaborate with AI. Are there any alternatives that have similar functionalities but lower hardware requirements?
p.s. My graphic card is RTX 2070, Win 10
I know there is llama + WSL2 manual to basically install the same AI Chat bot, but I love the idea of simplicity with nVidia one
